# Angular: get new DOM element from ngFor loop in component

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, element

I've not been able to accomplish one thing that should be quite easy in theory, and it's really bugging me.

So basically, I have a service which provides some data for an array, let's simplify it to be just an array of strings:

```
public myList: string[] = ['lorem', 'ipsum'];
```

In my template I'm creating list items for each entry in the array and assigning IDs:

```
<ul id="listGroup">
  <li ngFor="let item of myList" [attr.id]="'item-'+item">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I have some additional functionality, which extends the list and adds new items.
What I basically would like to do next is, to get access to each new DOM element that is created as a result of new items being pushed to the list.

I have attempted this by using ElementRef and the querySelector method of nativeElement.
Let's just say that I already subscribed to something in my component, which notifies me of newly added items in my array and it also provides the corresponding value, so that I can compile the correct element ID:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#item-'+item);
```

Altogether I'm putting this in an ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook and would assume that I would find each newly added DOM element. But nope! I'm just always getting a return of "undefined". So it seems like the DOM element is not yet available, how would I properly "wait" for the element to be there and accessible by my component?

I hope this makes it clear enough what my issue is, if not I might need to add some more code, that's a bit though on mobile though.

Thanks for any help!

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can can get elements reference. You can adapt to your case:

**Typescript Directive**

```
  .....

  @Input('focusOnInit') priority: number = 0;

  static instances: FocusOnInitDirective[] = [];

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    FocusOnInitDirective.instances.push(this)
  }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      FocusOnInitDirective.instances.splice(FocusOnInitDirective.instances.indexOf(this), 1);
    });

    if (FocusOnInitDirective.instances.every((i) => this.priority >= i.priority)) {
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" (click)=add()>Add</button>
<div *ngFor="let input of inputs">
  <input type="text" focusOnInit="3">
  <input type="text" focusOnInit="2">
  <input type="text" focusOnInit="1">
</div>
```

**Component typescript:**

```
  ....
  inputs = [];

  add() {
    this.inputs.push(this.inputs.length+1);
  }
```

And the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/O6MDYsPgaSovnqokOQxY?p=preview)

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid using a directive, but it seems to be the only reliable way in my case. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, my issue is solved :).